# Accessing nested elements in python

Tags: nested-lists

I am new to python.I am posting here for the first time and I know  question might be quite basic but problem is I can't figure out myself.

Lets say I have 
List=[("a,"b"),("c","d"),("e","f")]

I want the user to enter one of the elements of one of the tuples as input and the other element is printed.Or more precisely I would say that just one of elements in List[x][0] is  input and corresponding List[x][1] element is printed as output.I hope it makes sense.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check List in the question.I think you forgot a quote(") in the first tuple.[("a^here,"b"),("c","d"),("e","f")]
I think this might help you.

```
List=[("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f")]
c=raw_input('ENTER A CHARACTER-')
for i in xrange(len(List)):
    if c in List[i]:
        ind=List[i].index(c)
        print List[i][abs(ind-1)]
        break
```